# How can I use gerrit to push a change as a remote branch to the git repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm using a gerrit project that rebases changes to master. My workflow is

- Make changes in a local branch
- Gerrit push a change
- My local branch name becomes the gerrit topic for the review
- On submit in Gerrit, the change gets merged into remote/master.

I wanted to submit a change and cause it to become a new remote branch rather than rebased onto master. Is this possible using Gerrit?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Create a Branch**

There is command to create a branch:

`ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit create-branch myproject newbranch master`

[Reference](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-create-branch.html)

Or, you can do it like this:

```
git checkout master
git push origin HEAD:my_new_branch
git checkout my_new_branch
git push origin HEAD:/refs/for/my_new_branch
```

**Push changes to the Branch**

When pushing changes to gerrit use the -b flag with the new branch name. Otherwise gerrit will use the local branch name as a topic.

`-b, --branch BRANCH   Push to remote BRANCH`

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly still use remote branches. Depending on how your repository is configured they may or may not trigger a gerrit code review. Often that only happens when merging on the master branch.